# getting constant text size while using atop function in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, plotmath

Below is a much simpler example of a complicated custom function I have written. In the full-length form of this function,

- `"layer1"`corresponds to `caption` entered by the user,
- `"layer2"`
  corresponds to results from a statistical test, and
- `"layer3"`
  corresponds to details about the statistical test carried out.

But when all three layers are included in the caption, it looks something like this-

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()  +
  labs(caption = substitute(atop(substitute(
    atop("layer1", "layer2")
  )
  , "layer3")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

So I wanted to figure out a way I can keep the **text size constant for all three layers**. I am actually not sure why the text size automatically changes in this context.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little confused about the "substitute" in the plot, but perhaps the following solves the problem:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()  +
  labs(caption = substitute(atop(
    atop(displaystyle("layer1"), displaystyle("layer2")), "layer3")))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. Wasn't aware of `displaystyle(x)` and `textstyle(x)` functions (any reason to prefer the former over the latter?). The behavior I was getting was because `plotmath` defaults to `scriptstyle(x)` or `scriptscriptstyle(x)`?

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil, I immediately took `displaystyle` just because, in LaTeX documents, inline equations are somewhat smaller than display equations, and that's exactly the way to fix it there. Now it looks like `textstyle` is going to have somewhat less spacing, so you may see what you prefer. I'd guess that the default here is `scriptstyle`, and if you added, say, `atop`, it would be `scriptscriptstyle`.

Comment: Thanks. See my second part to the current question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239765/preventing-centering-in-plotmath-for-multilayered-text
Maybe you have some solution for this as well.